# Calculate distance (in percentage) from street given the current location of the house

Tags: percentages

I have 8 properties that run in a line on one side of the street (all houses have equal dimensions I.E. width * height * length ), there is a street that starts exactly from my first house and ends at the end of the last house . Given then above two facts I.E. 8 houses of equal dimensions and the street starts from the first house and ends at the end of the last house. Now i can make the below 2 statements.

If each house is a 100% then 8 houses is 800%. Also each house runs parallel to 12.5% of the street. Now if i stand at the beginning of the 2nd house , how far am i standing from the beginning of the street ?

The solution i came up with or rather copied half knowingly from somewhere is the following.

```
12.5 * 1 * 800 / 100 // so basically (house-width-in-percentage * current-house * total-area )/ 100
```

This works but i am not sure why or how ? i'am a novice , but would appreciate any help or input.

**Edit :-** keep in mind that the house index's start from 0 not 1 , so house 1 will be 0 and house 2 will be 1 and 3 will be 2 and so on.

Comment: This is not correct. If you are at the beginning of the 2nd house, you are only one house width away from the beginning of the street so you should get $100$ as per your question but the solution you have written will give you $200$ as if you were standing at the end of the 2nd house / beginning of the 3rd house.

Comment: @MathLover thanks you have an eagles eye and thats exactly what i want actually and sorry , for got a major detail , the house index's are not 1,2,3,4... but rather 0,1,2,3,... etc. edit made

Comment: @MathLover I understand that this solution works, but i'am not sure how and why , maybe i'am missing a fundamental concept in math.